# Refactoring two functions with opposite operands into one

Tags: c++, refactoring

I would like to refactor the following 2 functions so that the logic will be in one function with one parameter:

```
void zoom_in() {
  object.zoom_factor *= 2;
  object.width /= 2;
  object.height /= 2;
}

void zoom_out() {
  object.zoom_factor /= 2;
  object.width *= 2;
  object.height *= 2;
}
```

What I tried to do:

```
void zoom_in() {
  zoom_helper(true);
}

void zoom_out() {
  zoom_helper(false);
}

void zoom_helper(bool in) {
  float factor = (in ? 2 : .5);
  object.zoom_factor *= factor;
  object.width /= factor;
  object.height /= factor;
}
```

However I would rather have the `factor` be an `int`. Can I cleanly refactor this code?

Comment: Note that doing this with integers may lead to some oddities. If `object.width = 255` and you zoom in seven times, then out seven times, you end up with `object.width = 192`, even though `zoom_factor` is the same as before. (Also, why does zooming in make objects smaller?)

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array of function objects:

```
void zoom_helper(bool in) {
    static const std::function<void(int&)> mul = [](int& x) { x *= 2; };
    static const std::function<void(int&)> div = [](int& x) { x /= 2; };
    static const auto update[2] = { div, mul };
    update[in](object.zoom_factor);
    update[!in](object.width);
    update[!in](object.height);
}
```

I don't think this is much of a benefit though, and I would not personally write this except for fun.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this. Do I have to define the multiplication and division, or can I get them from the standard library?

Comment: You need to define them. It's not very difficult and not widely useful.

Comment: Could `mul` and `div` be made into lambdas?

Comment: You don't need to use `std::function` here. Also there is [`std::multiplies`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/multiplies)

Comment: I would not accept a PR (or approve a review) that turned the original code into this. Readability took a nose dive here.

Comment: @AdrianMole No, all lambdas have unique types so you can't put them in an array.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I agree completely. This is "bad clever".

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yeah, I think so too. Not gonna use this in the code. Good to know such thing exists though.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to refactor is just using an `if ... else` block:

```c
void zoom_helper(bool in) {
    if (in) {
        object.zoom_factor *= 2;
        object.byte_aligned_columns /= 2;
        object.rows /= 2;
    }
    else {
        object.zoom_factor /= 2;
        object.byte_aligned_columns *= 2;
        object.rows *= 2;
    }
}
```

But maybe you're looking for something more 'elegant' or 'clever'?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking to eliminate the duplication of the "essentially same lines of code". But maybe this is the only clean and readable solution to this.

Comment: @Utku  Sometimes, the simple solutions should be used.